# Get old input on session on failed validation redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get old input on a session when validation FAILS. I redirect back to the form page and it loses the 'time' session.  I've managed to get it working using a hidden input field and the second argument of /input::old.

Example here:

```
<input name="time" hidden value="<?php echo \Input::old('time',  
Session::get('time'));?>">
```

But I want to do it without the hidden input. Is there a way to do this? I am using laravel 4.2.

Here is my code.

```
//Controller

$myVar = Session::get('time');

if ($validator->passes()){
...logic uses time session and works fine...
}
else {
...pass the session back somehow to use again in the existing session(not a variable)..


Redirect::back()
 ->withInput()
 ->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Comment: `Session()->reFlash('time')` or `->flash('time')` might work? See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#flash-data).

Comment: I can only find examples of using flash and reFlash with messages which the user wants to display in the view. I don't really need to show it just used use it to submit the value on resubmit after fixed validation.I want the time value to persist during the redirect. Maybe i'm thinking about flash() wrong?

Comment: Which takes precedence in the Input::old method? The first argument or the second? I assumed you’d rather a ternarny operator using the session->has() method. Flashing a session just keeps it for a further request

Comment: i've tried multiple things but nothing works. The odd thing is i put another variable before the "time" variable called "date" and that one sticks during the redirect but the  "time" session will not.

Comment: Session::get('time'); everytime you call this method, do a session()->reFlash(‘time’); let me know if that worked

Answer (score 0):

from your controller return back with $myVar.

```
Redirect::back()
->with("time", $myVar)
->withInput()
->withErrors($validator);
```